# Can these queries be combined into one?

Tags: sql, mfc, jet

I have this MFC code to extract a list of names from a Microsoft Access Database:

```
// Extracts all the brothers from the specified tables into the passed in array
void CPTSDatabase::BuildBrothersArray(CStringArray &rAryStrBrothers)
{
    CWaitCursor         wait;
    CMapStringToString  mapStrBrothers;
    CStringArray        aryStrQueries, aryStrFields;
    CString             strText, strBrother;
    POSITION            sPos;
    int                 iTable, iNumTables;

    rAryStrBrothers.RemoveAll();

    if (m_dbDatabase.IsOpen())
    {
        strText.Format(_T("SELECT * FROM [Congregation Speakers] ")
                _T("WHERE [Congregation]='%s' ORDER BY Speaker"), (LPCTSTR)GetLocalCongregation());
        aryStrQueries.Add(_T("SELECT * FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherChairman=-1"));
        aryStrQueries.Add(_T("SELECT * FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherReader=-1"));
        aryStrQueries.Add(_T("SELECT * FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherConductorWT=-1"));
        aryStrQueries.Add(strText);

        aryStrFields.Add(_T("BrotherName"));
        aryStrFields.Add(_T("BrotherName"));
        aryStrFields.Add(_T("BrotherName"));
        aryStrFields.Add(_T("Speaker"));

        iNumTables = 4;
        for (iTable = 0; iTable < iNumTables; iTable++)
        {
            GetBrotherData(aryStrQueries[iTable], aryStrFields[iTable], mapStrBrothers);
        }

        sPos = mapStrBrothers.GetStartPosition();
        while (sPos != NULL)
        {
            mapStrBrothers.GetNextAssoc(sPos, strText, strBrother);
            rAryStrBrothers.Add(strBrother);
        }
    }
}

// Extracts all the brothers from the specified table / field
// A map is used so that we end up with a list of unique brothers
void CPTSDatabase::GetBrotherData(CString strSQL, CString strField,
                                  CMapStringToString &rMapBrothers)
{
    CRecordset  *pRecordset = NULL;
    CString     strBrother;

    if (!m_dbDatabase.IsOpen())
        return;

    pRecordset = new CRecordset(&m_dbDatabase);
    if (pRecordset != NULL)
    {
        pRecordset->Open(CRecordset::snapshot,(LPCTSTR)strSQL);
        while (!pRecordset->IsEOF() )
        {
            pRecordset->GetFieldValue(strField, strBrother);
            rMapBrothers.SetAt(strBrother, strBrother);
            pRecordset->MoveNext();
        }

        pRecordset->Close();
        delete pRecordset ;
    }
}

// Locates the Congregation that has the "Local" flag set
// The local congregation is the home congregation
CString CPTSDatabase::GetLocalCongregation()
{
    CRecordset  *pCongs = NULL;
    CString     strCong, strQuery;

    if (m_dbDatabase.IsOpen())
    {
        pCongs = new CRecordset( &m_dbDatabase );
        if (pCongs != NULL)
        {
            strQuery = _T("SELECT * FROM [Congregations] WHERE [Local] = 1");
            pCongs->Open( CRecordset::snapshot, (LPCTSTR)strQuery );
            if( pCongs->GetRecordCount() > 0 )
            {
                pCongs->GetFieldValue(_T("Congregations"), strCong);
            }
        }
        pCongs->Close();
        delete pCongs ;
    }

    return strCong;
}
```

As you can see, I have several tables where I am doing searches and added any unique names to a list. I don't want to overcomplicate anything but is it possible to combine this is a single query and pull out one `CRecordSet` that has one unique list of names?

### UPDATE

Having done a bit more research it seems I need a UNION.  So I need to combine the distinct results from these queries as a single column:

```
SELECT Speaker FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE [Congregation]='xyz'
SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherChairman=-1")
SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherReader=-1
SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherConductorWT=-1
```

The results should be sorted A to Z.

### UPDATE

Having done a bit more research it seems I need a UNION.  So I need to combine the distinct results from these queries as a single column:

```
SELECT Speaker FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE [Congregation]='xyz'
SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherChairman=-1")
SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherReader=-1
SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherConductorWT=-1
```

The results should be sorted A to Z.

### Update

I have tried:

```
void CPTSDatabase::BuildBrothersArray(CStringArray &rAryStrBrothers)
{
    CWaitCursor         wait;
    CRecordset *pRecordset = nullptr;
    if (!m_dbDatabase.IsOpen())
        return;

    pRecordset = new CRecordset(&m_dbDatabase);
    if (pRecordset != nullptr)
    {
        CString strSQL = _T(""), strName = _T("");

        strSQL.Format(_T("WITH CTE(Name) AS(")
            _T("SELECT Speaker FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE [Congregation] = '%s' ")
            _T("UNION ")
            _T("SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherChairman = -1 OR BrotherReader = -1 OR BrotherConductorWT = -1)")
            _T(") ")
            _T("SELECT Name FROM CTE ORDER BY Name ASC"), (LPCTSTR)GetLocalCongregation());

        try
        {
            pRecordset->Open(CRecordset::snapshot, (LPCTSTR)strSQL);
            while (!pRecordset->IsEOF())
            {

                pRecordset->GetFieldValue(_T("Name"), strName);
                rAryStrBrothers.Add(strName);
                pRecordset->MoveNext();
            }

            pRecordset->Close();
        }
        catch (CDBException* e)
        {
            TCHAR szError[_MAX_PATH];
            e->GetErrorMessage(szError, _MAX_PATH);
            AfxMessageBox(szError);

        }

        delete pRecordset;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

[image: Error]

### UPDATE 2

This seems to work fine:

```
strSQL.Format(_T("SELECT Speaker AS Name FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE [Congregation] = '%s' ")
    _T("UNION ")
    _T("SELECT BrotherName AS Name FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherChairman = -1 OR BrotherReader = -1 OR BrotherConductorWT = -1 ORDER BY Name ASC"), (LPCTSTR)GetLocalCongregation());
```

Comment: In the updated code you have one ')' without matching '('. You can easily check if you print the string. Or switch to C++ raw string literals to have a string that is easier readable. In Update 2: no need to call `GetErrorMessage` and `AfxMesageBox`, you can also call `ReportError`. And don't forget to call `e->Delete()`.

Comment: If you check your answer, unless I am missing something, it has one `(` (just after `AS`) and then two `)` characters. This is what I based that code on. But I have added my own answer as indicated which is a bit simpler for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the original answer, this is what works for my `CRecordSet`:

```
strSQL.Format(
    _T("SELECT Speaker AS Name FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE [Congregation] = '%s' ")
    _T("UNION ")
    _T("SELECT BrotherName AS Name FROM Brothers WHERE ")
    _T("BrotherChairman = -1 OR ")
    _T("BrotherReader = -1 OR ")
    _T("BrotherConductorWT = -1 OR ")
    _T("BrotherHospitality = -1 OR ")
    _T("BrotherInterpreter = -1 OR ")
    _T("BrotherMiscellaneous = -1 ")
    _T("ORDER BY Name ASC"), (LPCTSTR)GetLocalCongregation());
```

Answer (score 2):

Not having tried, just quickly hacked:

```
WITH CTE(Name) AS (
  SELECT Speaker FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE [Congregation]='xyz'
  UNION
  SELECT BrotherName FROM Brothers WHERE BrotherChairman=-1 OR BrotherReader=-1 OR BrotherConductorWT=-1
)
SELECT Name FROM CTE ORDER BY Name ASC
```

And please don't make up SQL strings dynamically from user unput, use parameterized queries instead or you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I store the first bit into? I am using MFC and CDatabase and CRecordSet.

Comment: And won't there be an issue with the fact that both tables use different field name? All new to me.

Comment: Nice quote about SQL injection. Just learning about it. Thanks @Werner Henze

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Just use that query as you used the other queries before. Create a CDaoRecordset (please on the stack, not on the heap), then while not EOF do GetFieldValue and MoveNext. The different names are no problem, of course the type of all Name values in CTE must be the same.

Comment: Ok I will try when next on computer. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you look at the code above I don't use user text. I showed simplified for brevity 

Comment: @AndrewTruckle If 'xyz' comes from an internal source, then fine. If it is input from external, then SQL injection can be done. On my system the returned numbers were unique. If on your system they are not, then change to "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM CTE".

Comment: @WernerHenze Yes, it comes internally from GetLocalCongregation. Thanks.